# How to ignore self signed certificate issue in request-promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, request-promise

I am using request-promise module for my node app to make some API call. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise

```
import request from 'request-promise';
let options = {
                method: GET,
                json: true,
                uri : "https://" +this.urls + endpoint,
                body: payload,
                rejectUnauthorized: false // This doesn't work
            };

let response = await request(options)
```

SInce the API what I am trying to use is insecure (having self signed certificate), the conncetion is failing with this error:

> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED

I know with "request" module, we could pass rejectUnauthorized: false , to handle such case. I am not sure how can I pass such option with request-promise module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding this to top of your code. But this approach is insecure.

```
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
```

Comment: But this option will make my whole node app insecure.. I just want to pass this as parameter like we do for "request" module.

Comment: true. may be you can create a new issue in their repo https://github.com/request/request-promise/issues

Answer (score 9):

For any one still searching for this:
add `strictSSL: false` to the options object works for me

Comment: +1.
Fixed my issue `Error: unable to verify the first certificate` when I made a request with `request-promise-native`